# Pre/Post patching scripts - Run script and get output from VM

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, patch

I want to run Pre/Post patching Powershell scripts with Azure Automaton account and get an output of the command  which ran Inside the VM, i.e. "Get-service"

I just followed instructions on Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/pre-post-scripts#interact-with-machines
and their script:
https://github.com/azureautomation/update-management-run-script-with-run-command

Additionally I've found a way to run command and it's executing on VM, but NO Output.

```
$ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'
Add-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
$rgname ="raimundas-rg"
$vmname ="test-win-vm1"
$ScriptToRun = 
@"
get-service "wuauserv"
"@
Out-File -InputObject $ScriptToRun -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmname -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ScriptToRun.ps1
Remove-Item -Path ScriptToRun.ps1
```

However it did not did the trick since it's using old AZrm cmdlet. and did not get output in logs. any suggestions how to run scripts on multiple Azure VMs and get output?

Comment: Check the accepted answer in the question this one duplicates. You need to ensure your own permissions can retrieve the result of the invocation in the first place. However, your code is outputting to the success stream already and so you should be able to retrieve the output programmatically as written, permissions issues notwithstanding. Troubleshooting issues with not seeing the output in this case might be a better topic for [sf].

Comment: Does anyone have this running as intended?
It uses OLD AzureRM module and it's not working -"no Azure VMs found"

https://github.com/azureautomation/update-management-run-script-with-run-command